# inserting comma in a large int number

Tags: c

i am trying to insert a comma in a large integer number eg, 870120000 and present it as: 870,120 and the last three digits are discarded. The format will allways be the same, ie., xxxxxxxxx number where i am only interested in the first 6 digits.

What i have been doing so fare is using snprintf:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char buffer[5];
   unsigned int lNum= 870120000;
   int cx;
   memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));

   cx = snprintf(buffer, 4, "%d,", lNum);
   buffer[3] = ',';
   printf("%s\n",buffer);

   cx = snprintf(buffer+4, 4, "321"); // Note 1 ???

   printf("%s\n", buffer);

   return 0;
}
```

My problem is that i am stuck at (comment // Note 1), how do I add the last next three digits in to buffer ?

in addition I would like to know if this approch is ideal or is there any better(easier) way to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using a 5-element buffer to try to hold 6 digits plus a comma? Why have 2  calls to `printf`? Just assemble the string you want to print in a large enough buffer and print it once.

Comment: depending on your runtime library, the format `%'d` might work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in two steps. First convert the lNum into a string, then cut the needed parts out of this string. Something like that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char tmp[256], out[256];
    unsigned int lNum= 870120000;

    sprintf(tmp, "%u", lNum);
    sprintf(out, "%3.3s,%3.3s", tmp, tmp+3);
    printf("%s\n", out); // prints 870,120 
    return 0;
}
```

See http://ideone.com/bnQNou
Or you can convert it into a float and change the locale to have "," as delimiter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int lNum = 870120000;

    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE");
    printf("%3.3f\n", (float)(870120000 / 1000000)); // prints 870,120 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lol. I did it but too slow ;). +1

Answer (score 0):

First of all to hold `870,120` you have to define a `8` chars `buffer`.

So you can use `%f` format specifier to do what you the job, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char buffer[8] = {0};
   unsigned int lNum= 870120000;

   snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%3.3f", (float)(lNum)/(1000000));
   char *temp = strstr(buffer, ".");
   if (temp != NULL)
   {
       *temp = ',';
   }

   printf("%s\n",buffer);

   return 0;
}
```

or another example using double `snprintf` and a given number of integer part digits and decimal part digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define INT_DIGIT 3
#define DEC_DIGIT 3

int main()
{
   char temp_buffer[128];
   char buffer[INT_DIGIT+DEC_DIGIT+2] = {0};
   unsigned int lNum= 87012000;

   snprintf(temp_buffer, sizeof(temp_buffer), "%u",lNum);
   snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%.*s,%.*s", INT_DIGIT, temp_buffer, DEC_DIGIT, &temp_buffer[INT_DIGIT]);

   printf("%s\n",buffer);


   return 0;
}
```